# Facebook connect, FBML: How do i get the user id?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have a dead simple Facebook connect app, that really doesn't do much besides getting the name and profile picture from the user that has connected with my website. But in order to show other users the profilePicture and name of the user taken from facebook i need to store the facebook profile id in my own database for my own renderings - but how do i get the user ID of the currently logged in user?

Can it be done in pure FBML? I need it to be as simple as possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

FBML is deprecated but XFBML isn't.

The simplest way in XFBML would be

`<fb:name uid="loggedinuser" use-you="no"></fb:name>`
`<fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" size="square" facebook-logo="true"></fb:profile-pic>`

Then alternatively via API

```
/me?fields=id,name,picture
```